# port 8082 on ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

When I nmap my computer I get this port open with this text

`8082/tcp open  blackice-alerts`

Do anyone of you know what this blackice-alerts is

netstat reveal this

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 @asad-linux-deskt:mysql *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:8082                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 @asad-linux-desktop:ipp *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 @asad-linux-deskt:43676 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:38148 hkg01s01-in-f113.1e:www ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:34919 tx-in-f101.1e100.ne:www ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:54513 hkg01s01-in-f102.1e:www ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:55928 a88-221-217-18.depl:www ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 @asad-linux-deskt:38277 @asad-linux-deskt:43676 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:51560 sin01s01-in-f104.1e:www ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:51561 sin01s01-in-f104.1e:www ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:53386 ec2-174-129-241-1:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:55927 a88-221-217-18.depl:www ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 @asad-linux-deskt:38270 @asad-linux-deskt:43676 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 asad-linux-deskto:41855 Asads-MacBook.loca:5900 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:netbios-ssn        [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5900               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:www                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ipp       [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:microsoft-ds       [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 *:59554                 *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                                
udp        0      0 asad-linux-d:netbios-ns *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:netbios-ns            *:*                                
udp        0      0 asad-linux-:netbios-dgm *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:netbios-dgm           *:*
```

Any ideas .......?

Comment: Just in case it's some web server: did you try http://localhost:8082 ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that's what is listening on 8082, rather than what nmap is guessing?  Try:

```
 sudo lsof -i tcp:8082
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has a "policy" of not having any ports open for security purposes. On a LiveCD of Ubuntu 9.10, I don't see port 8082 open, so something you installed started a service on this port. To find out what has it open, run netstat with the -p flag with sudo:

```
sudo netstat -plant
```

The last column will show a PID and a programs process name. You can find more detail about the running process by the PID listed from the output with:

```
sudo lsof -p:PID
```

(Where PID is the number)

You can find out what package installed that program with dpkg -S

```
dpkg -S
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a web-proxy (`webscarab`) running on `localhost` and that was running on `8082`. Netstat showed a java process (I guess `webscarab` is written in java and hence jvm is being invoked).

Closing Webscarab closed the port too.